# Will Square webhook subscriptions tied to merchant ID (not location ID) work reliably?

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

[The Square documentation for updating webhook events](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#put-webhooks) shows this URL format: `PUT /v1/{location_id}/webhooks`. However,  creating a webhook event listener for every merchant location could be a lot of separate API requests, and it would be far easier to use the **`merchant_id`** instead of the `location_id` (even though this is not documented) and make one request for each merchant.

Attempting to do this actually works - when I `PUT /v1/{merchant_id}/webhooks` the webhook is saved in Square and transactions for *any* of that merchant's locations successfully send the webhook.

My question is, since this is undocumented (although it works) is it safe to rely on this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may work currently, since it's undocumented, the behavior may change in the future and cause unintended side-effects. I strongly encourage you to follow the current documentation for subscribing to webhooks.